# Inner function scope in Javascript

Tags: javascript, closures

In [THIS](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-closures-with-ease/) article, I do not understand the following statement:

> Note that the inner function cannot call the outer function’s
>   arguments object, however, even though it can call the outer
>   function’s parameters directly.

Can someone please help me understand both the points mentioned

1. Inner function cannot call the outer function’s arguments object
2. Inner function can call the outer function’s parameters directly.

Comment: Do you know, what [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) object is?

Comment: Amazing. I was just about to post the same exact question, referring to the same exact article, but with a different title: *Closure: What does "call outer function’s arguments object" vs. "call outer function’s parameters directly" mean?* @Teemu's link answers it precisely. Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

The keys to understanding both of those statements are:

1. Understanding what `arguments` is
2. Understanding "shadowing"

So let's talk about `arguments`, then talk about shadowing, and then I think it'll be fairly clear what those two statements are trying to say.

#### `arguments`

The `arguments` object is provided as part of the scope within a function: It's effectively an automatically-defined variable that has a pseudo-array of the arguments the function was called with:

```
function foo() {
    console.log("My arg count: " + arguments.length);
}
foo(1, 2, 3); // My arg count: 3
```

When I say automatically-defined, I mean it's very much as though you had this:

```
// CONCEPTUAL, not real
function foo() {
    var arguments = /*...magic code to get the arguments we were called with */;
    console.log("My arg count: " + arguments.length);
}
foo(1, 2, 3); // My arg count: 3
```

...it's just that the JavaScript engine does it for you.

The `arguments` object is a lot like an array — as we saw above, it has `length`, and you can access the individual arguments using the usual `[]` notation:

```
function foo() {
    var n;
    console.log("My arg count: " + arguments.length);
    for (n = 0; n < arguments.length; ++n) {
        console.log(arguments[n]);
    }
}
foo(1, 2, 3);
```

Output:

```
My arg count: 3
1
2
3
```

You can even use named arguments and the `arguments` pseudo-array in the same function:

```
function foo(a) {
    console.log("a = " + a);
    console.log("arguments[0] = " + arguments[0]);
}
foo("Hi there");
```

Output:

```
a = Hi there
arguments[0] = Hi there
```

It's a *pseudo-array* because although it has `length` and `[]` indexing, it's *not* really an array and doesn't have all of the features normal arrays have (like `slice`, `forEach`, etc.).

In loose mode, it also has the very surprising property that it's *linked* to the named arguments, so you get weird stuff like this:

```
function foo(a) {
    console.log("before: a = " + a);
    arguments[0] = a * 2;
    console.log("after:  a = " + a);
}
foo(10);
```

Output:

```
befer: a = 10
after: a = 20
```

Spooky, eh? In strict mode, that link isn't there (because it's expensive for the engine to do that).

Okay, so that's `arguments`. What's this "shadowing" thing?

#### Shadowing

Functions create a "scope" for variables and such to exist in, and since you can have functions inside other functions, you can have scopes inside scopes. Functions inside other functions have access to the scopes that contain them, so:

```
function outer() {
    var a = 10;

    // `a` exists here

    function inner() {
        var b = 20;

        // both `a` and `b` exist here

        console.log("a = " + a + ", b = " + b);
    }

    // only `a` exists here

    inner();
}
```

`a` exists in the scope of `outer`, which `inner` has access to. `b` only exists within `inner`.

That's fine as long as we use different names, but suppose we used `a` for both of them:

```
function outer() {
    var a = 10;

    // `a` exists here

    function inner() {
        var a = 20;

        // `a` exists here -- but which one is it?

        console.log("a = " + a);
    }

    inner();
}
```

There, since `inner` has its own `a` variable, it can't access `outer`'s `a` anymore — `inner`'s `a` **shadows** (hides) `outer`'s `a`.

This is true for variables, named arguments, functions created within a scope, anything that gives a name a meaning within a scope.

So what does shadowing have to do with the two statements? Let's find out...

#### *"1. Inner function cannot call the outer function’s arguments object"*

"Call" is the wrong word here; "access" would make more sense.

Remember our conceptual example above, where `arguments` is basically an automatically-declared variable?

```
// CONCEPTUAL, not real
function foo() {
    var arguments = /*...magic code to get the arguments we were called with */;
    console.log("My arg count: " + arguments.length);
}
foo(1, 2, 3); // My arg count: 3
```

Now that you know about shadowing, you can probably see where this is going. This code:

```
function outer() {
    function inner() {
        console.log("Inner arg count: " + arguments.length);
    }
    console.log("Outer arg count: " + arguments.length);
    inner();
}
outer(1, 2, 3);
```

shows

```
Outer arg count: 3
Inner arg count: 0
```

...because inside `inner`, `arguments` refers to the `arguments` object for the inner function, not the outer one. It's exactly like they both declared a local variable with the same name: The variable in `inner` *shadows* (hides) the one in `outer`.

Now, *"Inner function cannot call the outer function’s arguments object"* isn't really true. The inner function **can** access the outer function's `arguments` object, but not by that name — if `outer` assigns it to a variable, though, there's no problem:

```
function outer() {
    var outerArgs = arguments;
    function inner() {
        console.log("Outer's arg count from inner: " + outerArgs.length);
    }
    console.log("Outer arg count: " + arguments.length);
    inner();
}
outer(1, 2, 3);
```

shows

```
Outer arg count: 3
Outer's arg count from inner: 3
```

#### *"2. Inner function can call the outer function’s parameters directly."*

This statement is incomplete: `inner` can access `outer`'s arguments **provided `inner` doesn't shadow them**. So this is fine:

```
function outer(a) {
    function inner() {
        console.log("Outer's a = " + a);
    }
    inner();
}
outer(10);
```

Output:

```
Outer's a = 10
```

...but here, `a` gets shadowed and so `inner` only sees its own `a`, not `outer`'s:

```
function outer(a) {            // <== declares a named argument `a`
    function inner(a) {        // <== ALSO declares a named argument `a`
        console.log("a = " + a);
    }
    inner();
}
outer(10);
```

Output:

```
a = undefined
```

So really, both statements are just about scope and shadowing.

Answer (score 3):

In the body of every function, there's a special array-like object called `arguments` that contains all of the actual arguments the function was invoked with.  For example:

```
function f() {
    console.log(arguments);
}

f('one', 2, 3.0);
```

Most languages would require you to declare those arguments, but JavaScript doesn't care how many arguments you use.

Since there's only one `arguments` variable in scope at any given time (at most), it makes sense that you can't access the `arguments` variable from an enclosing function:

```
function f() {
    function g() {
        console.log(arguments);  // will log ['blue'], not ['red']
    }
    g('blue');
}

f('red');
```

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Inner function cannot call the outer function’s arguments object

If you have

```
function outer(){
    function inner(){
       doSomething(arguments);
    }
 }
```

then `arguments` refers to the arguments of the function immediately containing the line. So to the arguments of `inner`. You cannot get to the arguments of `outer` from there.

> 2. Inner function can call the outer function’s parameters directly.

```
function outer(a,b,c){
    function inner(d,e,f){
       doSomething(a,b,c);
    }
 }
```

As long as you keep the argument (and local variable) names distinct, you can still access the parameters to `outer` from inside `inner` (here, those are `a`, `b`, and `c`).